# Where does PyCharm keep the error log for Python/Django projects?

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I am running a Django project locally using PyCharm and it is returning a 500 error on an API call. I think this signifies an internal server error so I am assuming the reason for and nature of this error will be in a log somewhere. But I can't find where it is.

Is such an error log kept? If so where?

Comment: Pycharm doesn't keep these kind of errors, you either need to integrate your own error logging or use debug mode

Comment: I tried debug mode but couldn't see where to pickup the cause of the error.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't PyCharm specific, but it might help. If `DEBUG=True`, Django will include the traceback in the response. If `DEBUG=False`, then by default Django will email a report to the users in the `ADMINS` settings.